# Android custom camera overlay without rewriting camera?

Tags: android, camera

I have been struggling with creating a camera preview with a custom layout/overlay that mimics the functionality of the native camera app.

Is there any way I can simply constrain the size of the native camera preview and possibly overlay a grid image on top of it without having to fully rewrite all of the camera's functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot hack the UI of another app, any more than another app can hack your UI.

Also, bear in mind that there is no single "native camera app". There are dozens, perhaps hundreds, across the thousands of Android device models.

Comment: Sigh.  OK.  That's what I figured.